# How does one fix peeling paint on a car?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

Do i need to repaint it? Its peeled to the black with silver paint.

Comment: A photo would help, though it sounds like a part repaint is inevitable.

Comment: Any photos of your car would be very beneficial.